# how to expire cached nimbus network image

Tags: ios, nimbus-ios

I'm having trouble with refreshing a nimbus image and not sure if I'm correctly removing the cached images.  After I upload a new image it still keeps showing the old image on refresh for a few minutes or more.

```
[(SDURLCache*)[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];

[[Nimbus imageMemoryCache] removeObjectWithName:url];

[profilePic setPathToNetworkImage:url];
```

Which way is the right way to remove the cache?

Comment: This should work for you now :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Will check it out today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new method to Nimbus' in-memory cache called `removeAllObjectsWithPrefix:`. You can use this method in the following way to forcefully expire images from the cache:

```
[imageView.imageMemoryCache removeAllObjectsWithPrefix:imageUrl];
```

You will need to know the url in order to expire it from the cache.

The reason why this method is necessary is because NINetworkImageView adds a suffix to the image cache key to differentiate between different sizes and content modes.

https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/src/networkimage/src/NINetworkImageView.m#L137